# How to restrict user to navigate back to previous pages and refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I am trying to build a website using ASP.NET MVC5. 
I am stuck.

Issue: I want that when user goes to a particular page he/she should not be able to refresh the page, go back to the previous page, copy anything, print screen.

Have tried different solutions like the followings:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
        history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
        window.onpopstate = function () {
            history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
            // Handle the back (or forward) buttons here
            // Will NOT handle refresh, use onbeforeunload for this.
        };
    }
    else {
        var ignoreHashChange = true;
        window.onhashchange = function () {
            if (!ignoreHashChange) {
                ignoreHashChange = true;
                window.location.hash = Math.random();
                // Detect and redirect change here
                // Works in older FF and IE9
                // * it does mess with your hash symbol (anchor?) pound sign
                // delimiter on the end of the URL
            }
            else {
                ignoreHashChange = false;   
            }
         };
     }
}
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return "Dude, are you sure you want to leave? Think of the kittens!";
    }
</script>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 || (e.which ||  e.keyCode) == 82) e.preventDefault(); };

$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on("keydown", disableF5);
});
</script>
```

but nothing seem to work.

Please suggest.

Comment: " I want that when user goes to a particular page he/she should not be able to refresh the page, go back to the previous page, copy anything, print screen" ; are you sure you really want a web app?

Comment: Yes. It would like an page when he/she would be taking an exam.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with javascript using the parameters of [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp), for example

```
window.open('yourUrl','windowName','toolbar=no');
```

However I would not recommend this. Instead (based on your comment to lujcon's answer) your should design your controllers and view models correctly to prevent the issues you have described. For example, if the user has already answered a question, add a flag, then if they trey to post another answer for the same question, you can check the flag and prevent an update/display error message etc.

Comment: Hey I am new to asp.net. Could you please tell me how to show any error message in the already loaded page from controller?

Comment: @priyam, That's the subject of a new question and depends on more detail and understanding of your app, but you could do something as simple as `<div>@ViewBag.Message</div>` and then in the controller `ViewBag.Message = "some message";`

Comment: Wouldn't that still reload/refresh the page as I still have to return the view?

Comment: @priyam, I can't give you a definitive answer without knowing more about what you actually doing, but as a suggestion, if the user navigates back to a previous answer and tries to post it, in the controller check if they have already answered it then redirect them to an error page with the message, or add a ModelState error and return the view. Or better, prevent caching and in the GET method, do the check and redirect to an error page. There a numerous ways you could handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do what you ask with a web application is to make all of your "pages" a single view that loads the results from multiple Action methods using AJAX. If you load everything using JavaScript/AJAX, the browser won't be able to keep track of any page history.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that! Web based applications means freedom. User should do anything she/he wants. The question should be: how should I design my application to handle back and refresh button correctly (not disabling them). Disabling printing is useless as at any time user can make print-screen...

Comment: Yes i agree. However lets say it's an exam website where user logs in to take a test and when he is done he clicks on submit and it takes him to the result page. The questions on the exam page is randomly generated and if he refreshes then the questions might change - Don't want that. After coming to the results page user can navigate back to the previous page(exam page) and change the answers - Don't want that. Please suggest how shall I handle it.

Comment: You can memorize current question id on the server side - and doesn't matter what page user will try to see - you'll know which question to show. You should memorize (on the server side) which questions are with answer and which are not and prevent from changing the answer...